# How to sniff/dump usb transfers for Android?

Tags: android, usb, dump

The device is rooted and supports USB OTG, android version is 4.x. It's my android application and it works in android code, but does not work in native code.

I need to get actual usb transfers log or debug output including controls transfers.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can recompile libhost (libhost.so) with debug output and inject it in system.